# Android Disappearing Portions of TextViews

Tags: android, textview

I have some text views in a table layout. When I click a button in my layout parts of the textviews disappear. I have tried restarting eclipse and the emulator a few times, but nothing has changed. This did not used to happen. I am completely stumped. Any suggestions for why this may be happening?

Before Click

[image]

After Click

[image]

Portions of the XML Code...

```
 <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_rank"
                android:stretchColumns="1" >

             <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:text="Public"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Parties Thrown:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicPartyAmount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" parties"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Average Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicAverageScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" points"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Biggest Party:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicBiggestParty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" guests"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Highest Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicHighestScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" points"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:text="Private"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Parties Thrown:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivatePartyAmount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" parties"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Average Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivateAverageScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" points"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Biggest Party:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivateBiggestParty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" guests"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Highest Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivateHighestScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" guests"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Well, can you post what you are doing in the onClick? Although now that I look at the image "after click" the first letter of the word did not diapered with the word..WTF?

Comment: My onClick method does not tamper with the textViews, also I don't think it's even possible to make part of a TextView disappear programmatically. Yes, very WTF indeed.

Comment: Could be in the layout? Are you using tables layout? Do post the xml .

Comment: Posted Code, yes I am using a table layout

Comment: @JamesFazio how you have solved this issue i am facing same in my case i have spinner too and if click on spinner and selecte item and than click or tap on any row than it hide all textview

Comment: @Khan this problem seems to only appear on the Emulator, have you tested on an actual phone device?

Comment: in my case it works on emulator and not on device if click on spinner and selecte item and than click or tap on any row than it hide all textview except the row on which i have tapped or clicked @JamesFazio

Comment: @Khan That is very strange, I'm sorry I have no idea how to fix this, sounds like a bug outside of your reach?

Comment: @JamesFazio Another person who had the same problem says he fixed it by removing the `android:layout_width="0dp"` from his xml file. Does it work for you too?