# Android Disappearing Portions of TextViews only first character is shown

Tags: android, scroll, textview, tablelayout

I have some Textviews in TableRows inside a table layout. In the same Activity I load images asynchronously. When I scroll down to display images parts of the textviews disappear and only the first character is shown.

The same problem has been reported here :
[Android Disappearing Portions of TextViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895811/android-disappearing-portions-of-textviews/14114272#14114272)

```
 // some code before ....
<TableLayout
   android:id="@+id/table_statistique"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/text_distance_desc"
   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:shrinkColumns="1"
   android:background="@drawable/bg_desc_parcours" >

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.5"
           android:background="@drawable/celltable"
           android:paddingBottom="20dp"
           android:paddingTop="20dp" >

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/layout_vitesse"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
               android:orientation="horizontal" >

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/picto_vitesse" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/vitesse_fiche_historique"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="5 Km/h"
                   android:textColor="#606060"
                   android:textSize="18sp"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />
           </LinearLayout>

           <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/layout_vitesse"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:text="VITESSE"
                   android:textColor="#11639e"
                   android:textSize="8sp"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />
       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="0.5"
             android:background="@drawable/celltable"
             android:paddingBottom="20dp"
             android:paddingTop="20dp" >

             <LinearLayout
                  android:id="@+id/layout_denivele"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                  android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <ImageView
                      android:layout_width="30dp"
                      android:layout_height="30dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                      android:src="@drawable/picto_denivile" />

                 <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/denivele_fiche_historique"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="100 m"
                      android:textColor="#606060"
                      android:textSize="18sp"
                      android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <TextView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/layout_denivele"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                  android:text="DÉNIVELÉ"
                  android:textColor="#11639e"
                  android:textSize="8sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
    // seconde row here
</TableLayout>
```

Edit: Code where I load my text

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fiche_historique);

            //... some code here


    distanceFiche = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_fiche_historique);
    deniveleFiche = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.denivele_fiche_historique);
    altitudeFiche = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altitude_fiche_historique);
    dureeFiche = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.duree_fiche_historique);
    vitesseFiche = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vitesse_fiche_historique);

            // ... some other code here

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        historique = extras.getParcelable("historique");
        if(historique != null)
        {
              // HERE IS THE CODE
              distanceFiche.setText(historique.getDistance());
             }
      }

          // ... some other code here

}
```

Any help please?

Comment: does the logcat print out anything? Show us the code where you load the text

Comment: thank you for replying, for the logcat it prints nothing. :s

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but in your code, where you initialize the TextViews, I only see `deniveleFiche` and `vitesseFiche` to be defined in the xml file

Comment: I did not put all the code from my xml because it is too large, dureeFiche and altitudeFiche are in a seconde TableRow in the same TableLayout

Comment: try stepping through the program using the debugger and see if you catch anything. Put you TextView on the `Watch` part of the debugger (assuming you are using Eclipse) and keep an eye on the frame and the text.

Comment: let me know how it turns out

Comment: it seems that no change affects TextViews, but when I scroll the display of TextViews change while in the debugger there is no change... I'm confused :s

Comment: I just tested on my Xperia X10, when I scroll TableRows disappear completely and logcat shows me **layout error:106 width:0 ellipsizedWidth:0** error

Comment: I found the solution I just removed `android:layout_width="0dp"` from RelativeLayouts.

Comment: that would do it. Good job :)